# pandas replace columns with cumulative sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe grouped by `customer_id` and `month` like this:

```
customer_id | month | total
1           | Jan   |  20
            | Feb   |  10
2           | Jan   |  20
3           | Feb   |  30
            | Mar   |  10
            | Apr   |  5
```

I want to use the `total` column to calculate the cumulative sum of all previous months up to the current month like this:

```
customer_id | month | total | cumsum
1           | Jan   |  20   | 20
            | Feb   |  10   | 30
2           | Jan   |  20   | 20
3           | Feb   |  30   | 30
            | Mar   |  10   | 40
            | Apr   |  5    | 45
```

I tried `df.grouby(['customer_id', 'month'])['total'].cumsum()` but didn't work, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your plain data frame(without grouping or messing with the indexes), just do `df.groupby('customer_id').cumsum()`.

Example:

```
import io
z=io.StringIO("""customer_id  month  total
1            Jan     20
1             Feb     10
2            Jan     20
3            Feb     30
3             Mar     10
3             Apr     5""")

df = pd.read_table(z, delim_whitespace=True)
```

yields

```
    customer_id  month      total
0   1            Jan        20
1   1            Feb        10
2   2            Jan        20
3   3            Feb        30
4   3            Mar        10
5   3            Apr        5
```

Then

```
df.groupby('customer_id').cumsum()


    total
0   20
1   30
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   45
```

And just assign it back

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('customer_id').cumsum()   

    customer_id month       total   cumsum
0   1           Jan         20      20
1   1           Feb         10      30
2   2           Jan         20      20
3   3           Feb         30      30
4   3           Mar         10      40
5   3           Apr         5       45
```

Comment: my dataframe has multi index 'customer_id' and 'month', when I applied your code, I got an error message "wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Comment: @efsee  reset your indexes.. `df.reset_index()`. This will make it easier